# ReactJS how to fire function on second time component is rendered

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to fire function every time except first one when component has been rendered? If so how could I achieve this?

Comment: You could use a flag and check that in your render method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact react has already something for you:

If you look at the docs for componentDidUpdate:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

> componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.

If you only want to execute on second time and not on third/fourth and so on, simply use some flag to make sure the function is executed only one time (so not on first render, but on second, and not on subsequent renders)

As a side note, an Update occur everytime a props/state change and shouldComponentUpdate return true. This may or may not be what you are looking for.